# Why am I getting HTTP 400 bad request even though script works on another machine

Tags: powershell

I have multiple servers/machines. one of the servers i use for development.

I am trying to run a simple powershell script that retrieves some values from a vault 
https://www.hashicorp.com/products/vault/

```
Function getValues($token) {
    $headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
    $headers.Add("X-Vault-Token", $token)
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod  -method GET -uri "https://vault.com:8243/v1/secret/vault/development" -ContentType 'application/json' -headers $headers
    $response.data| ConvertTo-Json  -depth 100
}
getValues $token
```

I am getting this error:

```
Invoke-RestMethod :
Bad Request

Bad Request - Invalid URL
HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

However, when i run the script locally (my computer) or from another server/machine, i get back a response and the values just fine.

Is there a reason why it works on one but not that machine? the servers are all the same setup (Windows 2016)

Proxy settings on machine that works and machine that doesn't work are the same:

[image: proxy]

Comment: Does it send a response when you use `Test-Connection https://vault.com:8243/v1/secret/vault/development`?

Comment: @RileyCarney `Test-Connection http://www.google.com` also fails, FYI. `Test-Connection vault.com` would make more sense.

Comment: Oops yeah should be without the `https://` that was my bad

Comment: @RileyCarney Test-Connection : Testing connection to computer
'vault.com' failed: No such host is known. I tried with google as well same error (Test-Connection http://www.google.com or even with just Test-Connection google.com)

Comment: @sodawillow hmm test-connection google.com fails for me locally and on the server

Comment: or I guess can you just use cmd and try `ping vault.com:8243/v1/secret/vault/development`?

Comment: and also `test-connection google.com` shouldn't fail that is very strange..

Comment: @RileyCarney it unfortunately does even locally: test-connection : Testing connection to computer 'google.com' failed: Error due to lack of resources

Comment: @RileyCarney C:\Users\>ping google.com

Pinging google.com [172.217.9.78] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Comment: Sounds like you either don't have connection to the internet or the firewall settings prevent the application (cmd/powershell) from accessing the internet on that device

Comment: @RileyCarney the thing is i get returned vault values just fine on my local machine/one of the servers. but the other server (development) i am getting the 400 ...

Comment: Check your proxy settings on the machine that works and the one that doesn't.

IE Browser -> Tools menu -> Internet Options -> Connections Tab -> LAN Settings button.

Invoke-RestMethod has a -Proxy parameter you can use to specify the proxy.

Comment: @RichMoss both settings are the same (check picture). I also tried the proxy parameter to no avail

Comment: Can you connect to port 8243 via telnet at a cmd prompt? `telnet vault.com 8243` A 400 error usually indicates you've connected to the server, or a proxy between, and the server/proxy is returning the HTTP status code 400 indicating the request is not valid. You can also run `tracert vault.com` to see which hosts are between the dev system and vault.com - one of the hosts might be returning 400 and failing to forward the request. That type of behavior is typical of a proxy or smart firewall like F5. Compare the `tracrt` between the working and failing hosts to eliminate a variable. Good luck!

Comment: @RichMoss so i actually just tried tracert from my local machine and it works, but i tried it from the working serve rthat i am getting a response from just fine, and request timed out. it also times out on the nonworking server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out after running netmon trace, the REST command was trying to call the url through the proxy.

I had the proxy on this nonworking server set in powershell profile that was created long ago. By commenting it out/removing these proxy lines, the rest calls were able to send back a response